# Not able to save changes to review model

Tags: product, customer, model, review

I tried to alter information from the table review_detail by loading the model, changing values and saving the model again, but being stuck.

The following code does not work:

```
$review=Mage::getModel('review/review')->load(12);
$review->setCustomerId(2)->save();
```

There is no error thrown, no error in the logs either.

Comment: use try {} catch {} for getting error

Comment: I had same problem when I was missing ->setStoreId(yourstoreid) so please try this

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I noticed that the problem occurs only with the column "customer_id", which is not saved. The other columns, such as "detail", "title" or "nickname" save without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review there exists the function _afterSave which seems to set the customer ID after saving the model. Thus overwriting the changes made before saving it.

I decided to solve my problem by creating a helper function to directly write the customer ID to the table review_detail:

```
public function saveCustomerIdToReview($reviewId,$customerId){
    $resource=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $writeConnection=$resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('review/review_detail');
    $query = "Update {$tableName} SET customer_id = '{$customerId}' WHERE review_id = " . (int)$reviewId;
    try{
        $writeConnection->query($query);
    } catch (Exception $ex){
        $this->logerror($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

One other solution would have been rewriting the _afterSave method in Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review.